# Rails: controller helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, controller, dry

If I have a methods that I want to use in several controllers, to keep my code DRY. 
What is the rails way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have your code reusable, I think `application_controller` is the best place to do so. Create any method you think it's reusable in multiple controllers in `application_controller` and call them in any controller you want.

Comment: another approach is to use mix-in modules, but I agree with `Someth Victory` start with `application_controller` and if things start to get out of hand then refactor to mix-in module(s).